# Product price is updated with Javascript half down

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price, javascript, custom-options, tax

I have a strange problem. I have a product with the price `81.50`, the tax is `19%`, so the regular price is `96.985`. In PHP I use rounding with half up. The price on product page is `96.99` which is corect, but when the page finishes loading the price is updated to `96.98`. What could be the problem?

Is there a function JS which updates the rounded price on page?

## Update 1

The problem is present only for products with custom options (ex: color), even if it has just one option and the price for it is 0.00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use a hack for this. Edit in `js/varien/products.js` file the function `formatPrice`:

```
formatPrice: function(price) {
    price = (Math.round(price*100)/100);

    return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat);
}
```